# When should I use "that one"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, determiners

I would like to know when I should use "that one" in a sentence.
Is it correct to write:

> I have read your two latest books: I found particularly interesting **that one** on ...."?

Comment: You use "that one" to point to a specific object. For instance: I showed him two cars of different color and after he had looked at both of them he said, "Yeh, I'll take that one," and pointed towards the red one.

Comment: But avoid "these ones" and "those ones" when pointing out multiple objects. Purists (like myself) will insist on "these" or "those".

Comment: @Mick - In some dialects, like mine, it's common to say "these ones" and "those ones", although I wouldn't do it in formal speech.

Comment: @stangdon It's very common in the UK -- even the BBC allow it. Unfortunately, it sets my teeth on edge.

Comment: @Mick - It drives my wife (from the Southern US) absolutely up a wall when I do it!

Comment: @stangdon Quite right, too! She sounds like a splendid woman.

Comment: In your example you are not really pointing to one of the books; you are just choosing it. So I think "I found particularly interesting *the* one on ...." is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

*That,this,those and these* are demonstrative pronouns used to point to specific objects.
There's no context to support such usage in your sentence. You speak about your personal preference, so the sentence should read

> I have read your two latest books: I found particularly interesting the  one on ....